# cant use local image as src laravel-mix vuejs

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-mix, laravel-vue

I have a Vue component located at `resources/js/modules/MyComponent.vue` and inside it, I'm trying to use a local image as an `src` for the `img` tag, and the image is located at `public/assets/myproj/image/myimage.png`.

I've tried using the following :

```
<img src="@/assets/myproj/image/myimage.png"/>
<img src="require('assets/myproj/image/myimage.png')"/>
<img src="../../../public/assets/myproj/image/myimage.png"/>
<img src="/assets/myproj/image/myimage.png"/>
```

but none of them work...

I know this is a straightforward question but I hope someone can help me because I've been trying to find an answer for almost an hour now but I still can't figure it out.

Comment: Image src path should be accessible to your server clients.

Comment: okay nvm i got it, imported the image instead using relative path

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use this in javascript you can do like this

```
<img :src='getImage(name)'/>
```

then you will need to import your image in your javascript code

```
getImage(name){
 return require(`@/assets/myproj/${name}`);
}
```